# 301 redirects in .htaccess on apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I guess this should be straightforward but my host got me to switch server from zeus to apache following which the .htaccess file with existing individual 301 redirects failed to work causing an internal server error, so have commented them out for the time being.  Could someone explain how to set these up to work in their new apache context?  Have no apache experience

Example redirect:

```
Redirect 301 /pages/exhibitions/thegreatindoors.html http://www.klassnik.com/pages/thegreatindoors.html
```

Read a lot about mod rewrites etc but not sure what to write. Thanks

Comment: Can you check Apache error.log to see what the actual error is.

Comment: I can't see it in the web/ directory not sure if i have access to it?

Comment: You need to ask server admins about it.

Comment: Found error logs think this might be it     [2014-08-18 21:14:58] [access_compat:error] [client 124.207.110.72:22706] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /mnt/website/standard/k/l/klassnik.com/web/.htaccess

Comment: That means `Redirect` directive is not allowed in your Apache config. Ask your server guys to enable it.